# capture only one photo of face per person and save it automatically (without pressing a key) in opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I'm trying to build a face detector with webcam using opencv in Python.
When human face is detected, the system need to be able to capture only one photo of face per person and save it automatically (without pressing a key), until the person leaves the frame and another person enters and again his face detected and saved in an image file.
I'm using a while loop for the live video stream and the continous face detection. I tried to create an inner while loop for saving the face photo, but it takes multiple frames.

The code:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    ret, img=cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, minSize=(150, 150), maxSize=(300, 300))

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

        face_img_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        face_img_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        laplacian_var = cv2.Laplacian(face_img_gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()
        #print(laplacian_var)
        
        if laplacian_var > 140:                          # avoid blur frame capture
            cv2.imwrite('Frame.jpg', face_img_color)
        cv2.imshow('img', img)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```